# How to add chat name in react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

I used normal chat bubble in react-native-gifted-plugin, and I want to add chat name on the top of the bubble and bold it. Is there a way to do that?refer the images.[image]

I used renderUsernameOnMessage prop to show username, How can I style that.It appears at the bottom. I want add it in the top of the bubble and bold it. Please help me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

renderCustomView prop can be used for this issue.